# What are the consequences of sending large amounts of header data to a Node/Express server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working with a Node server (running on Node 8) that runs using Express. This server only serves static files (with the `express.static` middleware). This configuration is given to it upon startup:

```
node --max-http-header-size=16384 dist/myServer.js
```

This server receives thousands of requests every minute, and recently, each request has close to 16k sized headers.

Our server has had much higher CPU usage than usual lately - could this be a consequence of sending too many headers in each of our requests? What are the consequences of sending large amounts of headers in HTTP requests to a Node server?

Comment: 16K, headers?..  That's large.   What are you sending in the headers?, large data should really go into the body.  Headers obviously get parsed, and that could certainly put strain on CPU usage.  But the body can be streamed, much better CPU usage.

Comment: @Keith The data is mostly noise, attached to each request by the reverse proxy we use to direct requests to each of our different servers. We don't use most of these headers on this particular server - I'm just wondering if this could be the cause of our recent CPU usage spiking lately, and if it's worth it to investigate lowering the number of headers sent to this server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending lots of large headers causes the following:

1. More memory used for each incoming http request
2. More network bandwidth used for each incoming http request
3. More CPU used to read and parse the headers on each incoming http request
4. Since headers are typically parsed into smaller pieces, this means more memory allocations and then subsequently more garbage collection which can also result in more CPU usage.

> I'm just wondering if this could be the cause of our recent CPU usage spiking lately, and if it's worth it to investigate lowering the number of headers sent to this server.

Yes, it is worth investigating whether these are contributing to your usage spike as lots of headers that you don't actually need are definitely contributing to wasted resources by your server.  How much they are contributing is hard to say.

As a test, you could configure an nginx proxy in front of your server that is configured to strip all the headers you don't need before passing them to your server and see how much that changes your server load.

Or if you have any control over the existing reverse proxy, then modify its configuration to remove the headers you don't need.